# Need Help in creating Dynamic SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using a SQL Server database. I have a SQL query which I have to write inside a stored procedure using SQL string and I am unable to write it.

The SQL query is

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [OfficeNo], [CustNo], [SAPNo],
    [Name1], [Name2],
    [HomePhone], [OtherPhone], [FaxPhone], [cellPhone], [workPhone]
FROM 
    [dbo].[tblCustomers]
WHERE 
    OfficeNo = '1043' 
    AND (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(HomePhone,'(',''),' ',''),'-',''),')','') = '6147163987' )
         OR (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(OtherPhone,'(',''),' ',''),'-',''),')','') = '6147163987'
         OR (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FaxPhone,'(',''),' ',''),'-',''),')','') = '6147163987'
         OR (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cellPhone,'(',''),' ',''),'-',''),')','') = '6147163987'
         OR (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(workPhone,'(',''),' ',''),'-',''),')','') = '6147163987'))))
```

The above SQL query works, but I am unable to convert the above REPLACE statements inside a dynamic SQL string due to lot of single quotes and colons. And it is throwing errors.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: I would suggest turning all the nested REPLACE into a function, and just call that function.  It will eliminate all the quotes and confusion, and centralize the code.  once you do that it will be much easier to create dynamic SQL.  Also what are you trying to turn into the dynamic parts if the above is working?

Comment: @jarlh i am using MS SQL( SSMS )

Comment: Have a trigger to make sure all phone no's are stored in a proper format - always!

Comment: Adding indexed persisted computed columns to your table containing the "tidy" versions of the telephone numbers would simplify queries and do wonders for performance. Tip: Never casually mention errors without providing the message and circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option. This is using an inline table valued function which is a whole lot better for performance than a scalar function. There are several ways this could work but I chose to pass in both the stored (or formatted) value in addition to the desired clean value. This lets us use cross apply to filter out those rows that don't match.

```
create function PhoneNumberCheck
(
    @StoredValue varchar(20)
    , @CleanValue varchar(20)
) returns table as return

select CleanValue = @CleanValue
where @CleanValue = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@StoredValue, '(', ''),' ', ''), '-', ''), ')', '')
```

Then to use this function we simply need to call it for each column of phone number values. One thing I should mention is in your original query you have top 1000 but you do not have an order by. This means you have no way of ensuring which rows you get back. If you use top you almost always need to include an order by.

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [OfficeNo]
    ,[CustNo]
    ,[SAPNo]
    ,[Name1]
    ,[Name2]
    ,[HomePhone]
    ,[OtherPhone]
    ,[FaxPhone]
    ,[cellPhone]
    ,[workPhone]
FROM [dbo].[tblCustomers] c
cross apply dbo.PhoneNumberCheck(HomePhone, '6147163987') hp
cross apply dbo.PhoneNumberCheck(OtherPhone, '6147163987') op
cross apply dbo.PhoneNumberCheck(FaxPhone, '6147163987') fp
cross apply dbo.PhoneNumberCheck(cellPhone, '6147163987') cp
cross apply dbo.PhoneNumberCheck(workPhone, '6147163987') wp
where OfficeNo = '1043'
--order by ???
```

Comment: all other solution were working.But, this one gave better performace. Will Index on above phone fields work in your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of SQL server you are using there are better ways to do this now, but here is a function I have to clean phones for 2012 and earlier.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CleanPhone] (
   @phone VARCHAR(20))
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS

BEGIN
   RETURN CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(NULLIF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@phone,
                    '`', 1), '{', ''), '}', ''),'_', ''), ' ', ''), '-', ''), '.', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), '/', ''), ''), 10)) = 1
               THEN LEFT(NULLIF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@phone,
                    '`', 1), '{', ''), '}', ''), '_', ''), ' ', ''), '-', ''), '.', ''), '(', ''), ')', ''), '/', ''), ''), 10)
               ELSE NULL
         END
END
```

Then call the function like this in place of all your NULL and IF statements and LEFT statements as all of them are done in the function above

```
SELECT dbo.fn_CleanPhone('1234-22(23)')
```

so this in your where statement:

```
where OfficeNo = '1043' 
AND (
    dbo.fn_CleanPhone(HomePhone) = '6147163987' )
    OR dbo.fn_CleanPhone(OtherPhone) = '6147163987' )
    OR dbo.fn_CleanPhone(FaxPhone) = '6147163987' )
    OR dbo.fn_CleanPhone(cellPhone) = '6147163987' )
    OR dbo.fn_CleanPhone(workPhone) = '6147163987' )
) -- end for and
```

Comment: Making this an inline table valued function would be a better approach for performance. Scalar functions are so slow.

Comment: If you have SQL 2016 the Translate function works better, here is link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

create a function to return the numbers of the input(sorry for bad naming):

```
CREATE FUNCTION GETCleand(@INPUT VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @INDEX INT = 0
DECLARE @CLEANED VARCHAR(MAX)=''
WHILE(@INDEX<LEN(@INPUT))
BEGIN
    IF(ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@INPUT,@INDEX,1))=1)
            SET @CLEANED = @CLEANED + SUBSTRING(@INPUT,@INDEX,1)
        SET @INDEX = @INDEX + 1
END
RETURN @CLEANED
END


SELECT TOP (1000) [OfficeNo]
      ,[CustNo]
      ,[SAPNo]
      ,[Name1]
      ,[Name2]
      ,[HomePhone]
      ,[OtherPhone]
      ,[FaxPhone]
      ,[cellPhone]
      ,[workPhone]
  FROM [dbo].[tblCustomers]
  where OfficeNo = '1043' and 
(GetCleaned(HomePhone) = '6147163987' 
  or GetCleaned(OtherPhone) = '6147163987'
  or GetCleand(FaxPhone) = '6147163987'
  or GetCleand(cellPhone) = '6147163987'
  or GetCleand(workPhone) = '6147163987')
```

when you have some `OR` and `AND` conditions on your `where` you should use parentheses on `OR` ones

Comment: Why did you use a loop here? The nested replace will blow the doors off that for performance.

Comment: @SeanLange I am iterating the string array and get the chars that are numeric based on question

Comment: But scalar functions are so slow and then adding a loop. >.<

Comment: @seanLang but what `Replace` function does inside? does it better to use multiple `Replace`?

Comment: It is a lot faster to use nested replace instead of loops. :) But for short strings the real difference is probably pretty insignificant. I just despise loops and find ways to eliminate them because most of the time they aren't needed.

Comment: @seanLang the `Replace` function does not magically replace items, it using `CharIndex` to find the desired chars and replace them using some iteration strategies, and I don't know why it should be a lot of faster than a loop?? ;-)

Comment: I have demonstrated the performance differences of this in the past. Let me see if I can find an example. The biggest issue though from a performance perspective is the need to use loops. They are just horribly inefficient.

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is to let TSQL do the loop without the performance hit when using a Row-By-Row query.

I have created a little test query hoping it will be easier for you to implement it in your case.

```
declare @table table
(
 id int
 ,PhoneNr nvarchar(18)
 )
 insert into @table
 values(1,'(123) 4567')
 ,(2,'123, 4567')
 ,(3,'123 4567')
 ,(4,'123 - 4567');

;with t1 as
(
    select PhoneNr, id from @table
    union all
    select cast(replace(PhoneNr, substring(PhoneNr, PatIndex('%[^a-z0-9]%', PhoneNr), 1), '') as nvarchar(18)), id
    from t1
    where PatIndex('%[^a-z0-9]%', PhoneNr) > 0
)
select t1.PhoneNr from t1
 where PatIndex('%[^a-z0-9]%', t1.PhoneNr) = 0
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

I would:

1. Replace the values entered in my test table with your test cases
2. Run the query and alter the regex if needed

integrate it into your table structure and cast the table phone column to in, if no error you will have achieved your transformation.

When you have your 'set up working' then compare the execution plans and you can pick your winner ;-)